# JS/CSS Card with description sliding up over picture on hover, expect transition height start top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

excuse me for my poor english I will try my best to explain my problem.

I like to have fun creating cool effects but I admit that the one I'm currently working on is starting to drive me crazy.

Here's what it is: [card](https://codepen.io/Craw_91/pen/zYywwKJ)

```js
$(".card").hover(
  function() {
    let desc = $(this).find(".card-description");
    desc.css("display", "block");
    setTimeout(function() {
      desc.addClass("show-desc");
    }, 20);
  },
  function() {
    let desc = $(this).find(".card-description");
    desc.removeClass("show-desc");
    setTimeout(function() {
      desc.css("display", "none");
    }, 2000);
  }
);
```

```css
/* automated conversion from SCSS */

.card {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #000;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 35px 0px #000;
}

.card:hover .card-thumbnail img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.card:hover .card-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
}

.card:hover .card-content .show-desc {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 150px;
}

.card .card-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

.card .card-thumbnail .card-date {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f7941d;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card .card-thumbnail img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.card .card-content {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05);
  transition: bottom 2s linear;
  bottom: 0;
}

.card .card-content .card-category {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f7941d;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
}

.card .card-content .card-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #f7941d;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 100px;
}

.card .card-content .card-description {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  word-break: break-all;
  transition: opacity 2s, height 2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-thumbnail">
    <div class="card-date">16</div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575936123452-b67c3203c357?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1hZ2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="card-category">Errors</div>
    <div class="card-title">
      SASS/CSS - Gérer les images au sein de symfony test test
    </div>
    <div class="card-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto corporis culpa cupiditate ducimus enim facere facilis fugit in ipsum labore, magni nihil perferendis qui rerumtemporibuslaboreaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
    <div class="card-comments">39 comments</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm almost there, there are only 2 problems left to solve.

- the appearance of the description is done from bottom to top but also the disappearance whereas I would like it to be done from top to bottom.
- if I place the mouse on the card then quickly exit and re-enter in, my JS code can't handle it.

How can I adapt it to my needs, preferably with as little JS as possible?

Thank you for all your assistance !

Craw

Comment: Why do you work with setTimeouts? This is the reason the behavior is weird when you quickly reenter..

Comment: Another way to delay transition is do to this in CSS itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

Comment: @Wimanicesir Because if I don't the display property cancel the transition and you can't apply delay on display property

Comment: You can use opacity instead of display. You can still use JS to set or unset classes based on a condition. But I would keep all animating instructions in CSS! As you said yourself: *preferably with as little JS as possible*

Comment: @Wimanicesir Opacity make it non visible but it still occupies the place. I advise you to try on your own to make it work and you will understand why I did what I did

Answer (score 0):

We can do this solely via CSS.

Basically, you can park all the transitions within the `:hover` CSS as what you've done here `.card:hover .card-content .show-desc`

The trick here is to grow the height of `.show-desc` on hover and have it animate. You can achieve this by animating the `max-height` of `.show-desc` on hover.

Something like this:

```
.card .card-content .card-description{
 max-height: 0;
 height: max-content;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

.card:hover .card-content .card-description{
 max-height: 300px; /* set to the max possible height for your desc content */
}
```

The rest of your `.card-content` doesn't need to be animated since the `.card-description` will animate and push everything else in place.